# Automating Windows Reset processs as much as possible

Tags: windows-11

This is something, I used to find myself doing occasionally, now that I am managing three windows PCs (Home, Work and on The go machine) its really becoming a hinderance, further more, I really need a solution that will minimise human errors and allow for conformity.

The things that I would like to automate:

- Rename the PC and user folder to what it was (so that the directory structure remains intact)
- Backing up and restoring windows "Open file with..." extension settings
- Backing Up and restoring [Windows Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/client-tools/windows-libraries) data
- Backing up and correctly Restoring Symbolic Links
- Backing up and Restoring all Environment Variables such as Path etc
- Restore the various settings that are found in the Modern Setting app such as

  - Taskbar position and if it shows on all monitors etc
  - Language settings
  - Disabling Hotkeys for Stick keyboard keys
  - etc
- Explorer settings such as quick access settings

and lastly a means of installing a series of executables silently with predetermined installation options. Some of the software's I am interested in installing, such as [Everything 1.5](https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=10479#-install), offer command line options to do this but I wonder if there are solutions that System admins rely on that are known to work on general installers.

I have picked up PowerShell (Core) and I feel fairly confident with it, so my plan is to write a script that will do the majority of these things in one go.

The problem I am facing is identifying how to achieve each one of these tasks in PowerShell, On a fresh windows Reboot, it will be Windows PowerShell that I have to work with.

For example, in the case of restoring windows "Open file with..." extension settings, is it really just a case of backing up this registry and then restoring it?

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```

I am not a System Admin at all and would love to hear input from such people.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do Keep Everything and nothing needs to be done

Comment: @John what do you mean? Are you reffering to Search Everything? Why would I need to do nothing else If I decide to keep Everything?

Comment: Keep Everything is Keep Data  and Keep Apps.  Everything including settings is retained.  I have done this numerous times.